# About password_hash() in PHP and storing (part of) its salt outside DB

Tags: passwords, hash, php, bcrypt

So, i learned that new in PHP 5.5 is password-hash() which works much like crypt(). Which is more secure (slower) than md5() or sha1(). The result string is algo+hash+salt, which can be passed as-is to password-verify() to verify password. So far i get how it works.

Some doomsday questions that remain:

Q1) What is the name of the result format/protocol/convention?

Q2) What i dont get however, is that all of the salt is included in the database. If a badguy® where to obtain these, he has *all* the puzzle parts. In the past, i learned to put (part of) the salt outside of the database: in source, of even base it on ram/system/hardware values so its not even on disk. Why is this not facilitated, or how should i? Ofcourse i could do a double hash with a different salt, or is there a better way?

Q3) Also -in the doomsday mindset that security requires- i believe the single-point of failure password_hash() is going to be a high value target, and might facilitate MITM attacks way easier than the more self-contained crypt(). I imagine writing a "bad" algo and setting it as the PASSWORD_DEFAULT algo would be easier than altering crypt(). I have not looked into the PHP backend code/modules however, just speculating.

Considerations welcome.
*Accepted answer will be the one that gets most up-votes/census for questions 2/3 within a week at most, and has question 1 verifiable correct.*

Comment: Perhaps i should add regarding Q2; i see hacking these selfdescribing hashes can happen more efficient and even fully automated.

Comment: I'd encrypt the hash with a key stored outside the db rather than keep the salt secret.

Comment: @CodesInChaos i wonder why do that using encrypt, and not hash? When do you need to decrypt it?

Comment: I'd first hash the password with bcrypt. Then encrypt the hash. That way an attacker who doesn't know the key can't do anything, and an attacker who finds the key still needs to run a password guessing attack against a slow hash. Using encryption over other keying methods has the advantage that you can easily change the key and re-encrypt the data. It's also convenient for scenarios where the key is stored on a separate system, such as a low performance HSM.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the name of the result format/protocol/convention?

`password_hash()`  uses the `bcrypt` algorithm.

> PASSWORD_DEFAULT - Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0). Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

> Q2) What i dont get however, is that all of the salt is included in the database. If a badguy® where to obtain these, he has all the puzzle parts. In the past, i learned to put (part of) the salt outside of the database: in source, of even base it on ram/system/hardware values so its not even on disk. Why is this not facilitated, or how should i? Ofcourse i could do a double hash with a different salt, or is there a better way?

The only requirement for a salt is for it to be globally unique. It does not have to be kept secret. `password_hash()` takes care of it for you. Don't do anything fancy and stupid. See: [How to store salt?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/17421/10211)

> Q3) Also -in the doomsday mindset that security requires- i believe the single-point of failure password_hash() is going to be a high value target, and might facilitate MITM attacks way easier than the more self-contained crypt(). I imagine writing a "bad" algo and setting it as the PASSWORD_DEFAULT algo would be easier than altering crypt(). I have not looked into the PHP backend code/modules however, just speculating.

What? MITM has literally **NOTHING** to do with this. The hashing should be done on the server. If an attacker can modify files on your server, he can already do whatever he wants.

Comment: You might want to mention the (rather small) downside of using bcrypt: since it's CPU-intensive to verify, it might be used in a DOS by sending many fake auth requests and forcing the server to spend a lot of CPU checking them all.

Comment: Thanks @Stephane i did not consider CPU usage being that high.

Comment: @Stephane I don't consider that a downside. Frankly, if that proves to be a problem you need a better CPU. Throttling login attempts should also help.

Comment: @TerryChia Thanks to the DoS potential one needs to choose relatively small cost factors for bcrypt, and even then it's tricky. Hashing on the client is actually better than hashing on the server in principle, but for that we'd need a high performance implementation of a password hash on the client.

Comment: @Barry Staes Benchmark and adjust the cost setting accordingly. For interactive logins, aim for something like ≤ 100 ms hashing time.

Comment: @TerryChia It's a problem in the sense that it is a side effect that must be understood by the application developer so that it can be taken into account in the design.

Comment: Q1: I understand that bcrypt is the default algo for now. But my question is how is the $algo$cost$salt+hash format called, when there are multiple protocols besides PASSWORD_BCRYPT. At least, i recon thats what they want to do.
Q2: Salt should be secret to avoid making a rainbow table.

Comment: Q3: Ok MITM is perhaps a misnomer here, meant not in the TCP/IP sense, it should demonstrate one potential attack vector to compromise software nobody looks at twice. One would be tempted to affect/replace this one function on a broad scale. Its a big target, and i wonder whats being done to alleviate that threat, if anything. (if you dont see this as a threat)