# Use password_hash() with a system-wide salt and a user-specific salt

Tags: php

This is somewhat a followup to "[About password_hash() in PHP and storing (part of) its salt outside DB](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/50872/about-password-hash-in-php-and-storing-part-of-its-salt-outside-db)".

Is there a way or any advantage to have a system-wide salt and a user-specific salt vs just a user specific salt? If so, how can I archieve that with that function? Is there a way to replace its internal salt generator with something as secure or more secure than it and then only store the user portion of the salt in the user table?

If the system salt is used, it will be stored in a different place in a specific server.

Comment: Feeding `password_hash()` an MAC of the password is easier. See `hash_hmac()`. The key you feed into `hash_hmac` would be your 'system-wide salt'.

Comment: @Darsstar So... something somewhat like this? `$store = password_hash(hash_hmac('sha512', $password, $sysSalt), PASSWORD_BCRYPT)`

Comment: That would work. But you might want to have `hash_hmac()` return the raw output. Just remember null bytes since bcrypt expects a null terminated string.

Comment: @Darsstar, @brunoais: Do NOT do pass `password_hash` the output of `hash_hmac`, as explained at: http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2015/03/security-issue-combining-bcrypt-with.html This is a security concern as it increases the likelihood of password collisions because `hash_hmac` can return null bytes, and `password_hash` stops hashing after the first null byte it encounters.

Comment: @0xdabbad00 I did mention null bytes and how bcrypt expects a null terminated string, didn't I? One can filter them out for example...

Answer (score 2):

That's called a "keyed hash" and the key is sometimes called "pepper."

Yes, there is a security advantage.  If the key is *not* stored in a database but is, perhaps, a constant in a program, then a database leak through SQL injection or similar will not reveal the key and your data will be nearly crack-proof.

Of course, if the OS gets owned, it sort-of doesn't make any difference what you've done.  However, it at least appears that many password leaks are due to SQL injection attacks.

There is an extremely useful essay on password hashing here: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm  It has a section on keyed hashes.  That essay recommends against hard-coding the key, and that's right if you're going to install a program in a number of places.  For a one-off installation, I still think it's OK.  Just be sure that the key is generated using a cryptographically secure random number generator (CSPRNG) in any case.

Comment: Hum... I better ask in stackoverflow about how to use that with `password_hash()`. Thanks for the information!

Comment: I'm no cryptographer, but I think you compute an HMAC with password and secret key, then pass the HMAC to the password hashing function as the "password."  I do know you can't just concatenate password and key; there's an attack against that.