# Why people buy stolen databases with emails and hashed passwords of users?

Tags: passwords, hash, rainbow-table

I see every now and then how hackers stole DB with emails and hashed passwords of millions of users from popular websites and sell it on the black market.

I assume that passwords were hashed with proper unique salt for each which makes rainbow tables useless.
And in the end, a consumer only gets emails and useless hashes.

**My question is, how it can be useful for anyone? The only possible reason as far as I can see is that they also provide salt for each password. Is my assumption correct?**

Comment: "consumer only gets ... useless hashes" -- you've made the leap in logic that the salted hashes are useless.

Comment: And this might be useful for you: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17421/how-to-store-salt The salt is part of the password database

Comment: it's useless for those who got the hash without salt

Comment: "Why do people buy these databases?" -- because they are useful. "How do the buyers get around the requirement to have the salt?" -- because they have the salt.