# How should an argon2 hash be stored?

Tags: encryption, hash, password-management, salt, argon2

Given the following argon2 hash

`$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=32,p=8$mJmKA5qamzXOPJZYw4wCEUKY$COkMH0RckaZ/3bhYCdCQjLuzoLKxcAmk4TzmHRRgTQ8`

How should the hash be stored in a database? [From the answers of this question it says you shouldn't store a salt in a database.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17421/how-to-store-salt)

But in the above argon2 hash we see the salt is `mJmKA5qamzXOPJZYw4wCEUKY`. So does this mean only the hash itself, `COkMH0RckaZ/3bhYCdCQjLuzoLKxc` should be stored in a database? I would assume all of the other information about the hash at the beginning (such as version, v, m, t, and p) wouldn't be stored for security reasons as well?

Comment: *"From the answers of this question it says you shouldn't store a salt in a database."* - it does not say this. In fact, the answers say that the salt can be stored together with the hashed password.

Comment: [This answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/17422/47524) correctly says *"A salt is not meant to be secret"*. May be the *accepted* answer confused you, because it contains a statement *"don't just give it out to anyone who wants it"*. This part of the answer means *security through obscurity* and thus is wrong. Even if somebody asks you for a salt, your can give it out. This will not break security. According to the [Kerckhoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) you should expect the the attacker knows the hash and the salt.

Comment: @user253751: *" If your design means everyone will have to see the salt..."* - How do come to this conclusion? I don't see any relation to my comment. If anything is not clear, please ask, I explain it better. You are trying to assign me *your* strange idea. Read my comment again.

Comment: @mentallurg There is no reason to give out the salt unless you have to. That's what the answers say. If you operated a website with password hashes would you give out a downloadable list of usernames and corresponding salts to everyone who wanted it?

Comment: @user253751: You change wording and give another meaning to the answer. The answer says *"don't just give"*. There is no reason not to give, if asked. If salt is known, it doesn't make the hash any weaker.

Comment: @mentallurg Do you put APIs in your web apps to allow clients to download salts?

Comment: @user253751: API? No, I don't.  But if I was asked for a salt, I would tell it.

Comment: @mentallurg what is the salt of the first user in your database?

Comment: @user253751: ecceaea5cf49920341c9e546523b48b2. So what? It is used only once. That's why there is no any risk related to it.

Comment: @mentallurg now please tell me the salt of the second user in your database. Do you see why this is a waste of time yet, or should I keep going?

Comment: @user253751: No. I don't see anything. You see all salts. So what? They all are different. Do you understand that knowing salt does not give any advantage?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145161/discussion-between-user253751-and-mentallurg).